# Huge Data Sync JOB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I need to `sync` huge amount of data from a customer system back to `MONGO` every day, or probably on demand. 
At any point in time, the data in **`SQL DB`** and **`MONGO`** collection should be in sync. We plan to write a data mapping file on **`how SQL data should be mapped to MONGO collection`**. What's the best strategy to do that on a daily, or hourly basis?

I need some guidance on how best we can do it ?. We use Node and JS for our stack.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did not work and why? SO is not a free solution design site...

Comment: You could use Kafka with a JDBC source and MongoDB sink. But real time synchronization is impossible to achieve, imho.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using MSSQL database then you should choose SSIS for data transfer(SSIS MongoDB Destination).